# Can I change change body element into another body element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, socket.io

It's very hard to phrase it in the title. Can I change the whole body element of a page into another body element? I want move user into another page but then their `socket.id` changes, so I figured I could just change all the elements into the elements of the next page.

Creating all elements from scratch and arranging them takes a lot of time. Is there a way to maybe save the whole body into a variable and then change the current body element for that one? Maybe I'd first save it somehow into a database and load it on the actual page after a button click?

Comment: What you are describing is a Single Page Application (SPA). There are entire libraries devoted to this, like React or Angular.

Comment: I think so. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @RobMoll I had no idea! Thanks I will investigate that further, but I'd prefer not to dive too deep into a whole another library just for this project.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm unable to save it into the database, the only thing that shows there are empty brackets {}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why I even bother asking questions here since no one helped me like ever lol.
But I found an amazing solution and its so simple!

I used `outerHTML`! You can paste a whole HTML markup inside just like that!

```
const gameelem = document.getElementById('game');
gameelem.outerHTML = `        <div class="title">
<h1>LOREM</h1>
</div>
<h2>
Lorem ipsum... <br>
Lorem ipsum...
</h2>
<h3>
Lorem ipsum... <br>
Lorem ipsum...
</h3>
<input type="text" name="" id="inputPrompts"><input type="button" value="OK" onclick="sendPrompt()">`;
```

Comment: Actually you can even use innerHTML. I have never seen it used like that so I'm super weirded out.